# What are the parameters for OpenCV cascade training for one object and black background

Tags: opencv, cascade-classifier

I'm trying to introduce an object with the OpenCv tool, but I did not do the cascade training.

My objects are one on the black background, and the negative ones are just black backgrounds.

Cascade does not recognize my object and focuses on the smaller things in the object, how can I overcome this problem?
Thank you

http://prntscr.com/ibvmt9

why is it not selecting all of my objects?

[image: why is it not selecting all of my objects]

Answer (score 0):

Having a look at your samples, your expectation of what the training process does seems to be a bit off.
What you need to do is supply multiple images *of the same object*. 
So create multiple positive samples as [described here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/dc/d88/tutorial_traincascade.html), and train that first.

Repeat this process for all the different objects you want to train on.
If you want to follow a tutorial, [try this out](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/db/d28/tutorial_cascade_classifier.html).

Enjoy!